# Using tokens to authorize in Sanctum

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I want to use React with Sanctum. In Sanctum, I generated the token and return it after login, and it works correctly. However, after login, I can see my token in the console, but if I want to open the route for logged-in users, I must send this token in the header. What is the best method to do that?

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $attr = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email|',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt($attr)) {
        return $this->error('Credentials not match', 401);
    }

    return response()->json([
       'access_token' => auth()->user()->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken,
       'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
}
```

And login into React.

```
function Login () {
    const emailRef = useRef(),
          passwordRef = useRef();

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login', { email: emailRef.current.value, password: passwordRef.current.value })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
    return(
       // Here is my form
    );
}
```

**@Edit**

I don't sure I good understand but it doesn't work. If I try to get address witch need to autorize I have a status 401.
I make instance
**instance.php**

```
import axios from 'axios'
let instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
    headers: {
        common: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }
    },
    withCredentials: true,
});

export default instance;
```

And I login user. In React it look like this

```
instance.post('/api/auth/login', {

        email: emailRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value
    
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

Generally it works. I want to add someting which need to authorize.

```
instance.get('/api/me')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.data.token);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

And in Api.php it look like this

```
Route::post('/auth/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);

Route::post('/auth/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::get('/me', function() {
        echo "Hello World";
    })->name('me');

    Route::post('/auth/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to not need to store anything in any special place by just using Axios config like this:

```js
axios.create({
    headers: {
        common: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        },
    },
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

The `withCredentials: true` will store the `CSRF` token and any credential once you login, so you would not have to worry anymore about *sending* any credentials or anything like so.

[This](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials/) is another example.

---

You could also take advantage of Axios and also delete any data you have store when a request returns `401` (Unauthorized) or `419` (Session Expired).

```js
authClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {
        if (error.response &&
            [401, 419].includes(error.response.status) &&
            store.getters[`user/${IS_GUEST_GETTER}`]
        ) {
            store.dispatch(`user/${LOGOUT_ACTION}`);
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

In this example, I am using a *store* like [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex) and I am asking first if the current user is a guest or not, and then deleting everything from the session with a simple logout (on Vue and Laravel).

You can do this with `Interceptors`.

Comment: I can't check this in this time but I don't sure that I good understand. I must create axios instance in separate file and use this instance in all requests? Problem 2: Token must be changed becouse Laravel return something like this `79|CX1202zNQCpUc2rqp88Bwa48aNQ1F6G5psfk1lLn` but i must use something like this  `Bearer CX1202zNQCpUc2rqp88Bwa48aNQ1F6G5psfk1lLn`

Comment: 1) Yes, you must return that Axios' created instance (sorry for not making that clear). 2) There should be no need, it should work out of the box. Maybe I am confused with cookies, sorry in that case.

Comment: It doesn't work. I updated my post, so you can check my code.

Answer (score 0):

How to Fix CSRF token issue using JavaScript (without jQuery)

Error I was facing.

> 419 PAGE EXPIRED

> message : "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"

My Route is protected with `auth:sanctum`, above snippet also worked with `auth` middleware.

```
Route::post('/media/upload', MediaController::class)
    ->middleware('auth:sanctum')
    ->name('media.upload');
```

1st add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in `app.blade.php`

2nd: Get the csrf-token value using `document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')`

**Snippet** headers settings

```
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
},
```

`"Accept": "application/json"` for 419 PAGE EXPIRED fixing.

`'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('me...` for CSRF token mismatch.

It worked either you are using axios, Ajax, XHR, uppy.io XHRUpload, or SPA

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/ajax',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    },
});
```